# Computing the power of the matrix $A$

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, matrix-decomposition

Let ${\displaystyle A={\begin{pmatrix}-1 &0&\cdots &0 &1\\-1&0
 &\cdots&0 &0\\0&-1 &\cdots&0 &0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots  \\0&0&\cdots&-1&0 \end{pmatrix}}}\in \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the finite field with $q$ elements and $n$ is a positive integer.

> Question: compute $A^k$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Attempt: I try to write $A$ as $P^{-1}BP$, but $A$ is not diagonalizable. Then I use mathematica to solve this problem for $n=4$ and $n=5$. It seems the following polynomial should be considered:
$$x^n+x^{n-1}+(-1)^n=0.$$
But I don't know why.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: are you interested in a closed form solution of $A^k$ for $n$ and $k$?

Comment: Yes, $\chi(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+(-1)^n$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$. So, by Cayley-Hamilton, $A^m+A^{m-1}+(-1)^nA^{m-n}=0$ for all $m$. I'm not sure that this recurrence relation leads to a nice formula for $A^m$. May be for some suitable $q$?

Comment: For example, if $n=p$, an odd prime, and $q=p^\ell$, then the matrix $B=A^{-1}$ satisfies the well-studied equation $B^p-B-I=0$. Implying $B^p=B+I$, $B^{p^2}=B+2I$, $\ldots,B^{p^p}=B$. That can probably be turned into some kind of a formula :-/

Comment: @CarlosCampos Yes. I am interested in a closed form solution for $n$ and $k$, I think the root of  the characteristic polynomial of $A$ could be used to simplify the solution.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is it possible to get a closed form solution from that recurrence relation?

Comment: Consider $B=-A$, then $B$ is a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). There are several methods to obtain a closed-form expression for the $n$th power of a companion matrix such as [*generalized Fibonacci sequence*](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/22-3/er.pdf) or by [*Combinatorial method*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379595901639). For more information, I suggest to see answer of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256638/the-nth-power-of-a-matrix-by-companion-matrix).